# C++ Regarding ifstream.ignore()

Tags: c++

There was some question i got in mind and would try to ask here..

Below is a operator overload

```
ifstream& operator>>(ifstream &input, Map2D &map2d)
{
    int x1,x2,y1,y2;

    //get x1 first
    input.ignore(2);
    input>>x1;

    //get y1
    input.ignore();
    input>>y1;

    //get x2
    input.ignore(4);
    input>>x2;

    //get y2
    input.ignore();
    input>>y2;
    input.ignore();
}
```

This is my text file

```
Map2D, [5, 7], [3, 8]
```

The question i got in mind is for , x2 as my delimiter is comma, why x2 is a ignore(4) and not ignore(2), i try ignore(2) and the figure mess up. but ignore(4) is the correct 1.

Why is it a (4) when theres only white space and a [

```
x2 refer to value 3
```

Thanks!! for explanining

Comment: Still at it, I see. Pray tell, why are you using hardcoded numbers, instead of using something like `input.ignore( LARGE_NUM, ']' )` or somesuch to read up to the next delimiter? Your `operator>>` will fail miserably for any two-digit numbers...

Comment: @DevSolar, how do i make it flexible to work with 2 digits too?

Comment: I feel your problem is not so much about *programming*, but more about *designing*, about breaking down a problem into logical parts. This cannot be taught in 500-character SO comment boxes, sorry. The basic idea would be to get a value pair - '[' to ']' - and then parse *that*. Once that is done, get the *other* value pair, and parse *that*. (At which point some part of your brain should automatically jump up and down and cry "Oh! Oh! I can re-use the code for reading a value pair!")

Answer (score 1):

You are skipping over "], [" which are four different characters.

When you read y1 you are still at the position of y1 in the stream. This position is before the end of the closing bracket "]" and then you have to read the comma, the white space and the next bracket "[".

Comment: But as i split by delimiter comma, i should be starting from white space then [

Comment: Well you haven't reached that delimiter yet. You are still behind a bracket. And I might be completely wrong but that means the stream will not skip that character. DevSolar is right though, you should be using ignore in the way he listed.